# Agrupar array por intervalo de fechas

Tags: javascript, array, typescript, d3.js, d3-v4.js

Tengo un Array ordenado de esta manera:

```
[
{fecha1: xxxx, key1: 0, key2: 1, key3: 0, ....},
{fecha2: xxxx, key1: 1, key2: 4, key3: 5, ....},
{fecha3: xxxx, key1: 2, key2: 3, key3: 3, ....},
{fecha4: xxxx, key1: 1, key2: 4, key3: 2, ....},
{fecha5: xxxx, key1: 0, key2: 1, key3: 1, ....}
]
```

Me gustaría agruparlo por intervalos de fechas de tal manera que si por ejemplo las fechas 1-3 fueran del mismo mes y las fechas 4-5 de otro mes distinto quedara así, sumando los valores independientes de cada key por fechas:

```
[ 
{mes1: xxxx, key1: 3, key2: 8, key3: 8, ....}, 
{mes2: xxxx, key1: 1, key2: 5, key3: 3, ....} 
]
```

Estoy usando d3.js nest() (aunque acepto cualquier otro tipo de solción con javascript/typescript), me lo agrupa por mes pero me crea un subarray por cada mes lugar de sumar los keys independientes. Creo que debeería usar un rollup o reduce pero no consigo hacer que funcione

La función actual (getMonth sólo parsea la fecha):

```
return d3.nest()
    .key( d => this.getMonth(d['date']))
    .entries(data);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer un reduce en el que dentro vayas creando el nuevo array que quieres devolver.

Dentro de este reduce, calculas el mes de la fecha y:

1. Si no existe, creas ese elemento del array con el mes en cuestión y todo a 0.
2. Sumas el resto de valores deseados, en el mes en cuestión, dentro de un bucle con las claves y los valores de las mismas.

Te dejo el código que lo verás más claro:

```js
//Tu array con ejemplos:

var array = [
   {fecha: '2019-02-01', key1: 0, key2: 1, key3: 0},
   {fecha: '2019-02-04', key1: 1, key2: 4, key3: 5},
   {fecha: '2019-02-11', key1: 2, key2: 3, key3: 3},
   {fecha: '2019-05-01', key1: 1, key2: 4, key3: 2},
   {fecha: '2019-05-11', key1: 0, key2: 1, key3: 1}
];

// Construcción del nuevo array:

var resultado = [];
array.reduce(function(res, value) {

    // Creamos la posición del array para cada mes
    let mes = new Date(value.fecha).getMonth();
    if (!res[mes]) {
       res[mes] = { Mes: mes};
    
       // Inicializamos a 0 el valor de cada key
       Object.keys(value).forEach(function(key) {
           if(key != 'fecha'){
               res[mes][key] = 0;
           }
    })

       resultado.push(res[mes])
    }
    
    // Sumamos el valor de cada clave dentro de un bucle
    Object.keys(value).forEach(function(key) {
     if(key != 'fecha'){
         res[mes][key] += value[key];
     }
    })

    return res;
}, {});

// Resultado:

console.log(resultado)
```

Espero que te sirva la solución.

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola Wyrncael, gracias por tu respuesta, la considero muy acertada. El único problema que tengo aquí es que todos los 'keyX' son nombres de claves que no vienen definidas por mí, y pueden venir con dos claves o con N. Aunque creo que podré hacer un bucle ahí con todas las claves que vengan? Gracias

Comment: Exacto, puedes hacer un foreach para las claves y coger el nombre de cada una para asignarlas.

Comment: @user115715 , he sacado algo de tiempo y he actualizado el código incluyendo el bucle que pedías. Espero que te sirva ;).

Comment: Hola de nuevo @Wyrncael ! En mi caso ya hice el bucle, pero te agradezco mucho que actualices tu respuesta para que sirva a más gente! Muchísimas gracias! :)